# Bootstrap 3 affix position after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have configured an affix that mostly works, as can be seen on this page: http://wisderm.com/ingredients/Green+Tea+Extract

This is my code for dynamically changing the affix offsets:

```
// nav-pills is the class of the <ul> element of the sidebar
// #hero-unit is the jumbotron

// where to start scrolling from
$('.nav-pills').affix( {
    offset: { top: function() { return $('#hero-unit').outerHeight(true)+10; } }
});

// after changing from affix-top to affix
$('.nav-pills').on('affixed.bs.affix', function() {
    $('.nav-pills').css("margin-top", function() { return -$('#hero-unit').outerHeight(true)+10; } );
});

// after changing back to from affix to affix-top
$('.nav-pills').on('affixed-top.bs.affix', function() {
    $('.nav-pills').css("margin-top", 0);
});
```

The problem is, once I scroll down to a place where `affix-top` has been changed to `affix` and I refresh the page, the affix that loads is a lot lower down the page than it should be. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

*Well, this is an old question, but the answer will help somebody:*

Your problem is fixed by **adding the event listeners before you initialize the affix**.

See thread in Github https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14331

try this:

```
// after changing from affix-top to affix
$('.nav-pills').on('affixed.bs.affix', function() {
    $('.nav-pills').css("margin-top", function() { return -$('#hero-unit').outerHeight(true)+10; } );
});

// after changing back to from affix to affix-top
$('.nav-pills').on('affixed-top.bs.affix', function() {
    $('.nav-pills').css("margin-top", 0);
});
$('.nav-pills').affix( {
    offset: { top: function() { return $('#hero-unit').outerHeight(true)+10; } }
});
```